# Aria-label and alt on a image

Tags: html, accessibility

To make an image accessible is it better to use aria-label or alt? Can both be used?
Example: `<img aria-label="Remove from favourites" alt="Remove from favourites" src="image.png" class="ng-scope">`

In this case the image is a star, if clicked only the borders remain and the item is removed from the favourites.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - ***[search for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=aria+vs+alt).